# Best practices for ActionMailer in Rails, when production domain isn't known/settled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I'm working on a hobbyist project and have reached the point where either of my next two most important features require sending email, and this is a place that all the guides I find online seem to gloss over a lot of seemingly important details.

My development environment is Windows + RubyMine.
My production environment will be Heroku.  (And probably SendGrid, maybe Mailgun, still evaluating).  I don't have real domain name yet, still evaluating/work-shopping a couple of options there.    It would be nice if the solution can work with a herokuapp domain name in the interim before I get the actual domain.

This will likely be an open source project, if it matters.  Ie there may be more than one dev, and not all devs are under a single domain name.

This feels like the development default for mail configuration should probably be gmail, with each dev configuring their own authenticated/2-factor/apppkey via environment variables.  While prod has the configuration for the chosen service provider/with authentication details via env variables.

Is this a reasonable approach?  It feels common enough to me that I would have expected some of the great guides to address it, but all seem to assume you'll use the same implementation in dev and prod, and that you already know your prod delivery system & domain name.

Answer (score 0):

> the development default for mail configuration should probably be gmail

The dev default should be something like the letter_opener gem. Do not send mails from your dev setup.

> prod has the configuration for the chosen service via env variables

Definitely true. ENV variables and also rails secrets, and yaml configuration files. My personal preference is to have yaml files (both for non-secret configs, read by `Rails.application.config_for` and the secrets file) with interpolated values from ENV:

```yaml
# config/action_mailer.yml
production:
  smtp_server: some-value
  smtp_password: <%= Rails.application.secrets.smtp_password %>
```

```yaml
# config/secrets.yml
production:
  smtp_password: <%= ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'] %>
```

this way you can abstract out where the config comes from. For instance, you can push a completely replaced secrets file in production, instead of injecting anything in ENV, and the application won't need to know the difference.

Comment: Thank you.  letter_opener looks like the piece that's been missing in most of the resources I've been looking at.